# How to handle returning array with forkJoin() in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using `forkJoin()` to handle multiple observables with this code:

```
forkJoin([
  this.userRoleService.getAll(), // result is an array of UserRole models
  this.userService.getOne(id), // result is a single User model
  this.countyService.all(), // result is an array of County models
]).subscribe(([userRoles, userModel, counties]) => {
  console.log(userRoles, userModel, counties);
  // handle the result
});
```

As you see in results I need to get two arrays and a single object. But in this scenario I get this in the console:

```
(2) [UserRole, UserRole]
UserModel {api_endpoint: "user/", role: UserRole, id: 1, name: "admin", email: "admin@admin.test", …} 
CountyModel {id: 20, name: "Hazard"}
```

Here I got one array with two of `UserRole` instances, one `UserModel` instance and one `CountyModel` instance.

Here is the `county.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CountyModel } from 'src/app/models/County.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountyService {
  db: CountyModel[] = [];
  constructor() {
    const items = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('counties'));

    items.forEach( (item: any) => {
      this.db.push(new CountyModel().init(item));
    });
  }

  all(): CountyModel[] {
    return this.db ? this.db : [];
  }
}
```

So the service's `all()` method return with an array in every case. But why I get only the last element of this array as result in the `forkJoin` and how can I catch all of the array elements?

Comment: If this is real code, the `forkJoin` will never complete, because the `getAll` method returns an array, not observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning observable of array in countyService, try wrap it with `of()`

```
forkJoin([
  this.userRoleService.getAll(), // result is an array of UserRole models
  this.userService.getOne(id), // result is a single User model
  of(this.countyService.all()), // result is an array of County models
])
```